# ¿Cómo insertar el valor dos llaves foraneas en otra tabla en MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, base-de-datos, datatables, tablas

[image: imagen de las tablaas de mi base de datos]

Buen día, tengo un problema y quisiera alguien me pudiera ayudar. Tengo una base de datos en la que estoy tratando de insertar en la tabla "dig_item", pero esta tiene dos llaves foráneas de las tablas "dig_pagina" y "dig_hritem", lo que necesito es insertar tal cual el valor de esas llaves foráneas en sus respectivos campos en la tabla "dig_item", sé como se hace un insert cualquiera y pienso que esto puede ser con "insert into select", pero al momento de insertar el valor de las llaves foráneas no tengo la menor idea de como hacerlo:

```
String SSQL = "(INSERT INTO dig_item "
        + "(ItemID,"
        + "HrItem,"
        + "PaginaID,"
        + "OpcionLeida,"
        + "TextoLeido,"
        + "NumeroLeido,"
        + "ConjuntoLeido))"
        + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,)";
```

Comment: ¿? El valor de las claves foráneas es un valor como otro cualquiera (como en tu caso es int, pues 13, o 42, o 144, o el que sea). Simplemente pones ese valor en el parámetro.Si no es ésa la duda ¿puedes explicar mejor cuál es el problema?

Comment: Está de más decir que si quieres insertar cualquier valor es estas columnas, los mismos deben existir en `dlg_pagina`?

Comment: Hola gracias por contestar!!!

Comment: los valores que estan en dig_pagina y dig_hritem ya estan en la base de datos, lo unico que quiero es formular el query para obtener las dos llaves foraneas en la tabla dig_item,sin necesidad de estar insertando yo manualmente

Answer (score 0):

Esta era la respuesta que buscaba :) tal vez no supe explicar que era lo que queria exactamente, muchas gracias a las dos personas que intentaron ayudar

```
                for (QuestionGroup group : structure.getQuestionGroups()) {                 
                int questionsCount = group.getQuestionsCount();
                for (int i = 0; i < questionsCount; i++) {    

                    String choices = sheet.getChoices(group, i);
                    if (choices != null) {
                        System.out.print(choices);


                    String SSQL = "INSERT INTO dig_item "

                            + "(HrItemID,"
                            + "PaginaID,"
                            + "OpcionLeida) "
                            + "VALUES ((SELECT HRItemID FROM dig_hritem WHERE NoItem = "+ (i+1) +"),"
                            + "(SELECT PaginaID FROM dig_pagina WHERE DigitalizacionID=1),'" + choices +"')";
```